# How to convert array to object in underscore?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

I have an array

```
var subject = ["Tamil", "English", "Math"];
```

I need to convert it to object as follows

```
[{
  "name": "Tamil"
 }, {
  "name": "English"     
 }, {
  "name": "Math"
}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Native JavaScript's `Array.prototype.map()` at this context,

```
var subject = ["Tamil", "English", "Math"];
subject = subject.map(function(itm){
  return {"name" : itm };
});
```

Answer (score 4):

With underscore:

```js
const subject = ['Tamil', 'English', 'Math'];

const out = _.map(subject, el => ({ name: el }));

console.log(out);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.13.4/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Native JS using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const subject = ['Tamil', 'English', 'Math'];

const out = subject.map(el => ({ name: el }));

console.log(out);
```

Comment: Thanks!! Perfect answer for my question. I thought it can't be done using Native JavaScript. But if it is possible in Native Javascript, then it is the best to use I feel. So, accepted the above answer.